# Change of variables for the Riemann sum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, riemann-sum, change-of-variable

Let $f :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function (or any smooth function will be okay as well).

Then, I am a bit confused about limit of the sum of the following form:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n f(k^2/n^2) \frac{1}{n^2}
\end{equation}

I do not see how I can perform the change of variables to figure out this sum converges to some integral of $f$ as $n \to \infty$.

Could anyone please explain?

Comment: Are you sure the summand isn't supposed to be $f(k^2/n^2)k/n^2$ instead?

Comment: @RobPratt shouldn't it be  $n^{-2}$ attached to $f$? To be a sort of $dx$

Comment: @CalvinKhor I was aiming for $\int_0^1 x f(x^2)\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: right sorry I understand you now

Comment: But maybe it requires a non-uniform partition.  Waiting for response from OP about the summand.

Comment: No $k$. I expect the answer to be proportional to the integration of $f$ only..

Comment: Actually, if the formula is right, then this should be zero, because \begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n f(k^2/n^2) \frac{1}{n} \to \int_0^1 f(x^2)dx
\end{equation}

Comment: I agree with @CalvinKhor ... Taking $f(x) = 1$ or $x$ or $x^2$ of $e^x$, I always get $0$ for your limit as $n \to \infty$.